# How to output text of NSMutableArray element count to iPhone label

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

```
NSUInteger arrayLength = [annotations count];

    UILabel* arrayLengthLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
    arrayLengthLabel.text = @"%@", arrayLength;
    [self.view addSubview:arrayLengthLabel];
```

I have the above code, which I have researched.

The problem is when outputting the arrays length count to the label.

I should have 4 elements in the array, but this is not outputting the number of elements, and I am sure I am making a schoolboy error here.

Cheers for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I would use:

```
int arrayLength = [annotations count];
UILabel* arrayLengthLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
arrayLengthLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",arrayLength];
[self.view addSubview:arrayLengthLabel];
```

I'm using a standard int and using the code `%i` instead of `%@`. This may be your issue. I don't know offhand if an `NSUInteger` requires `%i`, but I definitely know `int` uses `%i`.

Also, I don't know if your way of doing an `NSString` works without testing, so I've used the "full" format, which I know definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way :

```
UILabel* myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(25, 100, 110, 100)];
myLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", [myArray count]];
[self.view addSubview: myLabel];
```

Comment: `NSArray`'s `count` method outputs a `NSUInteger` which is just a 32/64bit unsigned integer and I don't believe it responds to `stringValue` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW71 I think you're thinking of `NSNumber`

Comment: Oops, you're right. My mistake. I'll change that, even though the other answers use this too.

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes as follows:

```
NSUInteger arrayLength = [annotations count];
UILabel* arrayLengthLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
arrayLengthLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arrayLength];//changes made here
[self.view addSubview:arrayLengthLabel];
```